# Wrong Grok pattern

Tags: logstash, logstash-grok

I am trying to make a grok pattern for the following trace of a log:

```
"source":"<a href=\"http://twitter.com/download/iphone\" rel=\"nofollow\">Twitter for iPhone</a>"
```

The grok pattern I've done is:

```
a href=\\"http://twitter.com/download/(?<Client>\b\w+\b)
```

Which seems to work well in any grok debugger online I have tried. However, when I run logstash, I got a grok parserror. This is my logstash configuration:

```
grok { match => {"message" => "a href=\\http://twitter.com/download/(?<Client>\b\w+\b)"}
```

Can you tell me what I am doing wrong? I don't understand why it does not work on logstash but seems to work in any online debugger.

The expected output is: `Client: iPhone`

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I think you could change your approach to avoid to handle all /" chars ;) so

The line :

```
grok { match => {"message" => "a href=\\http://twitter.com/download/(?<Client>\b\w+\b)"}
```

could be replace by :

```
grok { match => {"message" => "*%{URI}\/download\/(?<Client>\b\w+\b).*"}
```

Comment: I replaced it with your solution but I still got the same error.

Comment: Ok, I totally change my answer, I got a new regexp that match your data sample.